# Discover Report Not Populating Recent Send Data

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting

In a client instance of SFMC, our Discover Report for Recent Email Send Summary (filtered to prior 7 Days) has quit populating data. If I extended the filter to the last 30 days, I get results up to 04/02/2021 but nothing after. We do have sends going out since that date and they appear in the "Recent Email Sending Summary" (non-Discover Report). Anyone else having a similar issue? Do you have a solution or workaround?

Comment: I would review the E-I-L in the top level account and ensure its running: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_di_restart_paused_account.htm&type=5

Comment: Great hint @EazyE - the automation was having an error in Step 10 and I've escalated it to SF for resolution.